# Is there a fairly good free resource for dungeon dressing and common object lists?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

We play 'Loosely' in the D&D 3.5 system. I tend to create adventures on the fly, much of it is story driven in the world my players and I have fashioned over twenty years of play. So I use various computer tools to help me along in spots where something game mechanic-y needs to be rolled. Lately I am coming up short in the describing random object department for treasure.

*My question is this*

Is there a fairly good free resource for dungeon dressing and common object lists?

Not the "here are twenty things randomly rolled for you" but a comprehensive list near or over a hundred items long.

I have googled several times and come up lacking, so while that might be a suggestion unless you have found a decent quantity in your search I'll pass on the "just google it" comments, if that's okay.

I'll be making a table to randomly roll these things up in [TableSmith](http://mythosa.net/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.TableSmith).

Which I'd love to share with everyone once done, if that could be any incentive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of tools I've made use of in the past:

[Barrel, Crate and Sack Generator](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20070427a&dcmp=ILC-RSSDND) - Quick tool by wizards for random bags of supplies

[John's Dungeons and Dragons Utilities](http://jtevans.kilnar.com/rpg/dnd/tools/) - A simple website with a bunch of different tools for generating random stuff.  Everything from objects and treasure to traps and names.